# How to Catch/ Handle Error on the Supabase callback URL (OAuth)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth, supabase

I am testing on a project using Supabase OAuth provider and the OAuth-Ui, and is pretty cool, But I noticed if for example I try to login in a different provider like Github, I can see the error on the callback URL from supabase like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/?error=server_error&error_description=Multiple+accounts+with+the+same+email+address+in+the+same+linking+domain+detected
```

Well I guess this is normal since I already Sign in using google provider with the same email, but the issue is that return 200 anyway with this callback so how can I catch this error in order to display on the frontend ? Now nothing happen on the screen so this is a bad user experience, we have to tell somehow the user that he is already use the same Email on another provider.
I wasn't able to find out how to do this using the Supabase Auth UI with Next js app dir in their doc or I might miss somewhere...

this is an example using the OAuth UI from supabase to sign in on a modal:

```
 //...

const AuthModal = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>();

  // Zustand custom hook
  const { isOpen, onClose, view } = useAuthModal();

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async(event) => {
      if(event === "SIGNED_IN") {
        router.refresh();
        onClose();
      }
    })
  }, [router, onClose, supabase.auth]);


  function onChange(open: boolean) {
    if(!open) {
      onClose();
    }
  }

  return (
    <Modal 
      title={view === "sign_in" ? "Welcome back" : "Sign up"}
      description={view === "sign_in" 
        ? "Login to your account" 
        : "Or sign in with your favorite account"
      }
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onChange={onChange}   
    >
      <Auth 
        theme="dark"
        magicLink
        providers={["github", "google"]}
        socialLayout="vertical"
        supabaseClient={supabase} 
        view={view}
        appearance={{
          theme: ThemeSupa,
          variables: {
            default: {
              colors: {
                brand: "#404040",
                brandAccent: "#10b981"
              }
            }
          } 
        }}
      />
    </Modal>
  )
}
export default AuthModal;
```

Comment: The Auth UI is meant for simple use cases and nothing more than that. In this setup you could just catch the querystring since it contains the error in it and display a message to your user about this. Also if you log in with two different providers while having the same email it should automatically link the accounts, so I think there is something else going wrong here.

Comment: @Andrew Smith Oh catch the querystring i see... !  for the providers if you mean it should link to the same account than looks like it solved when I remove all the account in supabase to add back again it correctly link to the same, I will see about the catch error..